# Three js: Transparent object adds color to DOM underneath the canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, three.js, opacity

I'm working on a project where i would like to have objects floating around a webpage,
you can see the progress [here](http://kabkopendagfrontpage.bram-de-leeuw.nl/basic/).
I'm now using a 2d plane to float the objects around, it's the same size as the div behind it and i've set the plane's opacity to 0.

This creates the desired effect but there is one problem occurring. The objects float around the div and become invisible when behind the plane, that's good. The renderer is transparent `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});` so i can see the DOM underneath, that's good to. But the transparent plane that hides the floating objects adds a white color to the DOM. This only happens to DOM elements behind the plane. When dom behind the canvas is not behind the plane the proper colors are shown.

This is the code to create the plane:

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(160, 400), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
plane.overdraw = true;
plane.position.x = 0;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = -100;
plane.material.opacity = 0;
```

### edit:

The problem was caused by the material type. By using a `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` instead of a `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()` and adding a color to the material `plane.material.color = '0xffffff'` the problem got solved! The final code to create the plane looks like this:

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(160, 400), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
plane.overdraw = true;
plane.position.x = 0;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = -100;
plane.material.color = '0xffffff';
plane.material.opacity = 0;
```

Hope this helps people facing the same problem.

Comment: You plane is not transparent. You must set `material.transparent = true`. Also `overdraw` is not a property of a `Mesh`.

Comment: Hi West, thanks for your reply. By setting the `material.transparent = true`. The objects floating behind the plane would also be visible. The desired effect should be the objects floating behind the DOM thats behind the canvas. By changing the material from normal to basic and adding a color to the material, the problem got solved!